# Laravel pagination is not working with date search

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a couple of search forms in my app in which pagination works great, but when it comes to date search I only get the first page, when I try to go to the second page I get an undefined $ticket variable. When I look at the URL I can see that it doesn't take the date values with him to the next page.

Here is my code:

```
<tbody class="searchTable">
  @foreach($ticket as $tickets)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{Carbon::parse($tickets->created_at)->format('m/d/Y')}}
        </td>
        <td><a href="/ticket/{{$tickets->id}}">{{$tickets->id}}</a></td>
        <td><a href="/ticket/client/{{$tickets->clientName}}">{{$tickets->clientName}}</a></td>
        <td>
            {{Carbon::parse($tickets->dueDate)->format('m/d/Y')}}   
        </td>
        <td>{{$tickets->refNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{$tickets->invoiceNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{$tickets->jobLocation}}</td>
        <td>{{$tickets->workDescription}}</td>
        <td>{{$tickets->jobStatus}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody> 
{!! $ticket->appends(Request::only('_token','search'))->render() !!}
```

This is the controller:

```
  $ticket = DB::table('tickets')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$newDateFrom, $newDateTo])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
  return view('ticketsView', compact('ticket'));
```

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. I need to append the date values to the render.

Comment: can you give an example, pls?

Comment: Okay, I have the same view for different search requests so I append the results to the paginator so it will have it on the next pages as well. The name is the value of the name attribute in the search form. In my case I had multiple. Here is an example:

{!! $ticket->appends(Request::only(['dateFrom'=>'dateFrom', 'dateTo'=>'dateTo', 'search'=>'search', 'filter'=>'filter', 'dueDateFrom'=>'dueDateFrom','dueDateTo'=>'dueDateTo']))->render() !!}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I have the same view for different search requests so I append the results to the paginator so it will have it on the next pages as well. The name is the value of the name attribute in the search form. In my case I had multiple. Here is an example:

```
{!! $ticket->appends(Request::only(['dateFrom'=>'dateFrom', 'dateTo'=>'dateTo', 'search'=>'search', 'filter'=>'filter', 'dueDateFrom'=>'dueDateFrom','dueDateTo'=>'dueDateTo']))->render() !!}
```

So now if my search results will contain in the URL dateTo and dateFrom values for example then it will be saved to all pages. It's important to understand that these values come from the name attribute of your search form.

Here is an example:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="GET" action="/ticket/searchresults" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="text-centered">
     <p><strong>Search by dates:</strong></p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="filter">Select Client (optional)</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="filter" type="text">
       <option disabled selected> -- select client -- </option>
       @foreach($selectClient as $selectClients)
         <option value="{{$selectClients->name}}">{{$selectClients->name}}</option>
       @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="dateFrom">From:</label>
     <input class="datepicker2 form-control" name="dateFrom" type="text" required/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="dateTo">To:</label>
     <input class="datepicker2 form-control" name="dateTo" type="text" required/>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></span></button>
 </form>
```